# Finding $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\hat{f} \notin L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

I heard there were functions  $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\hat{f} \notin L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Is there a concrete example of such functions ? 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $r > 0$. Then
$$
     \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-rx}e^{-isx}dx=\frac{1}{r+is}.
$$
The function $f(x)=e^{-rx}\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)$ is in $L^1$, but $\hat{f}(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(r+is)}$ is not in $L^1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Do you think there is also an example with $p > 1$ ?

Comment: @anonymous : I will try to find something for you.

Comment: The Fourier transform is an isometry on $L^2$. No such example exists for $p=$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre : There is an interpolation between $L^1-L^2$ and $L^2-L^\infty$ as well, and that complicates finding examples in tables of transforms. Do you know of one right off?

Comment: The Fourier transfor sens $L^p$ into $L^q$ for $1\le p\1le2$, $1/p+1/q=1$. It is not defined (as a function) in $L^p$ for $p>2$. $x^{-a}\chi_{[0,\infty)}$, $0<a<1$ should give examples.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre : A lot of transforms that are not defined in the Lebesgue sense are well-defined as improper integrals, complete with valid inversions. Any positive real decreasing function on $[0,\infty)$ tending to $0$ at $\infty$ is a classic example of a function with a valid transform.